What is the relationship of namarupa and appearance?
i read this on a website:
"...Nama is the appearance of Rupa, 'what it looks like' and not 'how it is',.."
is it correctly said?

'what it looks like'...e.g. like a sex-object, but that is not how it is...

It's too short to know without context, but by itself it would mean our experience of things is just a mental image or concept, not the thing itself or how it really is. For example, if you had x ray vision things would look a lot different, even though the objects you see would still be the same as ever.
However, the next line in the article explains what he means:

In other words, Rupa by itself cannot be said to exist. It must appear and there must be consciousness to recognise it.

So it's saying without consciousness to know a thing, the thing may as well not exist, or doesn't, as far as you know. (If a tree falls in the wilderness and no one hears it, did it actually happen... Prove the Moon exists when you're not looking at it...)
The suttas say consciousness arises when two things make contact: the sense organ and the type of object it can perceive. If they don't make contact, that type of sense consciousness doesn't arise. An analogy in SN 12.67 regarding dependent origination is two sheaves of reeds leaning against each other; remove one and the other falls. Ajahn Brahm said,

consciousness is like the screen, nama rupa is like the movie on the screen. the point is you can't have a movie without a screen; you can't have consciousness without an object of consciousness, and you can't have an object of consciousness without consciousness. that's why they're called mutually dependent. -from "DAY 3 Q N A BY AJAHN BRAHM"

So the snippet is not incorrect, in that Teachings on interdependence are standard, and that you can see just by reason that without consciousness, you can't be conscious OF anything existing. When you're asleep the world disappears.

'Namarupa' was originally a term from pre-Buddha Brahminism, which referred to God using his will to name a multitude of names from the three basic forms of earth, fire & water. The SamaVeda, that evolved into the Chandogya Upanishad, say:

That Deity, having entered into the three gods (three elements of
earth, fire & water), saw, ‘I shall manifest name and form, the
unmanifested name and form which, as seeds, exist in me’… Name and
form came into existence on account of this action of multiplication
brought about by the triplication of the (three) elements by the Will
of the Supreme Being…

This 'namarupa' is similar to what is found in the opening of the Jewish Bible (most modern scholars accept that Genesis is a redacted literary work, reaching its final version as late as post-exilic Judea around 400 BCE; in other words; composed in Babylon from existing influences), which says:

In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth. Now the
earth was formless and empty, darkness was over the surface of the
deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters.
And God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light. God saw that
the light was good, and he separated the light from the darkness. God
named the light “day,” and the darkness he named “night.” And there
was evening, and there was morning—the first day.
And God said, “Let there be a vault between the waters to separate
water from water.” So God made the vault and separated the water
under the vault from the water above it. And it was so. God named
the vault “sky.” And there was evening, and there was morning—the
second day.
etc etc
Genesis 1

The Buddha appeared to adopt the term 'namarupa' for the purpose of redefining it:

And what, bhikkhus, is name-and-form? Feeling, perception, volition,
contact, attention: this is called name. The four great elements and
the form derived from the four great elements: this is called form.
Thus this name and this form are together called name-and-form.
SN 12.2

A detailed answer is here.

https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/vishnu/nasadiya.pdf

Thank you. Very good.

It's not correctly said. Speaking correctly one would say:

"Feeling, perception, intention, contact, & attention: This is called name. The four great elements, and the form dependent on the four great elements: This is called form." SN 12.2


If SN 12.2 is correct, is the different namarupa in DN 15 incorrect?

What do you think is the difference?

Read Name and Form and Rupa.
The form/body is built by Rupa/matter. The form/body is some collection of Rupa/matter.
Name means conciseness/mind.

Nama is the appearance of Rupa,

One has to read it carefully.
Yes. Nama is the appearance of Rupa.
Not the appearance(appearance/how it looks like) of the rupa.
But the appearance/Recognition itself.
That's because conciseness can't exist without a focus object/rupa. Conciseness arises when rupa is recognized.
